# C# Datatable to Dictionary

Tags: c#

C#:

I have a datatable with a variable number of columns - returned by calling a stored procedure. 
and I  would like to convert it to Dictionary key-value pairs (string). 
How do I achieve this without having to iterate through each column in each row? I won't know how many columns are there in the datatable at any time.

Thanks
G

Comment: not clear to me. lets say your DataTable has columns `A B C`; `n` rows with values `A1 B1 C1; A2 B2 C2; A3 B3 C3...` What dictionary are you expecting to get? what are the keys and values of desired result?

Comment: note that whaterver the result you need, you will have to iterate on rows and I assume columns, since you dont' know how many cols you have. Linq can get helpful in writing shorter and concise code, but internally it will iterate on rows and/or columns

Comment: The table looks something like this: ID  Name Type ... 1   ABC   Meeting. I am looking to get following format: "ID": 1,  "Name" : ABC, "Type": Meeting and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your result should contain values for the first (and only) row of the dataTable

This one liner can do the trick

```
    var res = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col=>dt.Rows[0][col]);
```

ToDictionary will internally enumerate the columns

But I really prefer this explicit enumeration:

```
var row = dt.Rows[0];
var res2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    res2.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
```

The second is much more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this calling the extension method ToDictionary() :

```
internal Dictionary<string,object> GetDict(DataTable dt)
{
   return dt.AsEnumerable()
  .ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>(0),
                            row => row.Field<object>(1));
}
```

Comment: The above code returns the following:1 ABC; where 1 is the productId and ABC is product name. I would like the following format: ID: 1, Name:ABC, Type:Meeting, etc.

Comment: You can build up any value you want for the key, you could even use a class and not a single value, just change the selector for the value (row => row.Field<object>(1));) to be whatever you want?